# Git Merge Two Remote Branches

Tags: git

I am creating a Azure DevOps Pipeline to create release branches when changes are committed to develop. The current release branch is release/1.2.

If the release branch doesn't exist then I want it to create it. Otherwise, I want to merge develop into the release branch. However, I keep getting the error "fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories"

I tried adding --allow-unrelated-histories to the merge, but then get a merge conflict even though the release branch is a direct copy of develop and I only made a single update to the develop build.yml.

> CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in build.yml
> Auto-merging build.yml
> Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

```
git config --global user.email "AzurePipeline@example.com"
        git config --global usver.name "AzurePipeline"
        echo "##[command]remote update origin --prune"
        git remote update origin --prune
        git branch -r | findstr /snip origin/release/$(MAJORMINOR) >NUL  2>NUL
        if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0  (
            git fetch origin
            git branch -D release/$(MAJORMINOR)
            git checkout -b release/$(MAJORMINOR) origin/release/$(MAJORMINOR)
            git merge origin/develop
            git push origin release/$(MAJORMINOR)
        ) else ( 
            git checkout -B release/$(MAJORMINOR) origin/develop
            git push -u origin release/$(MAJORMINOR)
        )
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Update: Adding git log --all --graph --oneline for develop and release/1.2

develop

```
2b73d9e5 Update build.yml for Azure Pipelines
* 3501192b Update build.yml for Azure Pipelines
* bdf4fc98 Update build.yml for Azure Pipelines
* 74c812a0 Update build.yml for Azure Pipelines
* 53cc130c Merged PR 5549: Update Baseline_AGI objects from develop branch
* 1392f59d Merged PR 4346: v10 Documentation into Main
* 770c8d84 Merged PR 3674: Merging to Documentation Branch
* cdce2559 Merged PR 2485: Updated Access Genius Insights (AGI)
* 4f56d350 Merged PR 1163: Competitor Suggestion
* cfc6defc Merged PR 326: Merging v4 changes to Main
* 676bd79a Adding build pipeline for the Baseline_Messaging solution
```

release/1.2

```
2b73d9e5 Update build.yml for Azure Pipelines
* 3501192b Update build.yml for Azure Pipelines
* bdf4fc98 Update build.yml for Azure Pipelines
* 74c812a0 Update build.yml for Azure Pipelines
* 53cc130c Merged PR 5549: Update Baseline_AGI objects from develop branch
* 1392f59d Merged PR 4346: v10 Documentation into Main
* 770c8d84 Merged PR 3674: Merging to Documentation Branch
* cdce2559 Merged PR 2485: Updated Access Genius Insights (AGI)
* 4f56d350 Merged PR 1163: Competitor Suggestion
* cfc6defc Merged PR 326: Merging v4 changes to Main
* 676bd79a Adding build pipeline for the Baseline_Messaging solution
```

Comment: If the histories are unrelated, it will be extremely hard that the merge of stuff will come out fine.... I would ask: why are the branches you are trying to merge unrelated?

Comment: That is my question. What is making them unrelated? The remote branch was made off of develop via git checkout -B release/$(MAJORMINOR) origin/develop
            git push -u origin release/$(MAJORMINOR)

Comment: But colleagues might do with the remotes what they like? So they can be unrelated? perhaps have a look at the history (graph using git log --all --graph --oneline) but you need to checkout the branches...

Comment: Eventually, but I am building this in a sandbox, so there are no colleagues at this point. I run the code once to create release/1.2 then make a change in origin/develop and run the code a second time and they are now considered unrelated histories. I will update the question to have the graphs.

Comment: Very likely due to a shallow clone, which doesn't do a full clone, but only fetches a single commit (the latest one). Your `git log` output is fishy: both histories are identical (so there is nothing to merge, it is literally the same commit)